# Html code in jQuery text attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've been trying to add `<br>caption<br>` on `'text'` property unsuccessfully. What am I missing here?

```
// Hover Title
   var hover_link = jQuery("<a>", {
   'text': article.data.title + '<br>caption<br>',
   'target': 'blank',
   'href': article.data.url
   });
   new_hover.append(hover_link);
```

Comment: You can use `html` property. http://jsfiddle.net/Gu9Ek/

Comment: Using the `text` property is the same as calling `.text(...)`.

Comment: It means that you have some text in html `div` and you are trying to add `<br>html- caption<br>` after that text? is it like this? Suppose you are having `<p>Hello</p>` then you want after adding it to be like this `<p>Hello html caption </p>`. Did you want to do like this?

Comment: After re-reading http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html, i don't see a 'text' attribute for anchor. Anyone else noticed or can guide me about this?

Comment: Exactly, I have a title and then a description that I would like to add below the title, using <br> or <p>

Comment: @Satpal with html property just works, thank you.

Comment: @MilchePatern you are right, 'text' is not an attribute, I'm using 'text' like content of the element.

Answer (score 0):

```
var link = $("<a href='" + article.data.url + "' target='blank' text='" + article.data.title + "<br>html-caption<br> + "' />");

new_hover.append(link);
```

Is this what you meant? Your question is not very clear.

Comment: I apologize, my english is not good enough. I would like to use <br> or <p> on 'text' property. Satpal has suggested using the html property. Now works well :-)